# Find the limit of the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$ given that $a_{n+1}^2=a_na_{n-1}$ and $a_0=2,$ $a_1=16$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have the following sequence:

$$a_{n+1}^2=a_na_{n-1}, \forall n \ge 1$$

With $a_0=2$ and $a_1 = 16$. I am also told that the sequence has **positive** terms. I have to find the limit of the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$.

I am not that great at limits/sequences so I'm not sure how should I approach this.

Comment: If you calculate a few terms, you'll see it appears to be approaching $8$

Comment: It might be easier to instead think about the sequence $b_n = \log_2a_n$.  Then you've got $b_0 = 1$, $b_1 = 4$, and $b_{n + 1} = \frac{1}{2}(b_n + b_{n - 1})$.

Comment: WA says this here $$a(n)\to 8 e^{\frac{1}{3} (-1)^n 2^{1-n} (\log (2)-\log
   (16))}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $b_n=\log(a_n)$ which makes
$$2 b_{n+1}=b_n+b_{n-1}$$ which looks to be simple.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Do the AM version first.

If $b_{n+1} = \frac{b_n + b_{n-1} } { 2}$, then $\lim b_n = \frac{ b_1 + 2 b_0} { 2}$.

Apply to $a_n = 2^{b_n}$.

Comment: When you wrote $b_0+2b_1$, did you mean $2b_0+b_1$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner . Agreed. Must be a typo.

Comment: Thanks, fixed..

Answer (score 0):

With $a_n=2^{b_n}$, the sequence $b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3...$ is $1, \,3+1,\, 3-1/2,\, 3+1/4, \,3-1/8,...$ Prove that $A(n)\implies A(n+1)$ when $n>0,$ where $A(n)$ is $b_n=3\pm 2^{-(n-1)} \land b_{n+1}=3\mp 2^{-n}$. And so by Induction on $n$ , obtain $b_n\to 3.$