# Sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{x_n x_{n-1}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $0<a<b<\infty$ be real numbers and define the sequence $x_1=a$, $x_2=b$,  $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{x_n x_{n-1}}$. Find the limit of $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$.

So I have proved that the sequence is a contraction  and that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (x_{2n+2}-x_{2n+1})=0$. Therefore the sequence converges to some number $x$ in the interval $(a,b)$. Numerically, I have found that the limit is actually $x=(ab^2)^{1/3}$, but I'm stuck in actually proving this result analytically. A hint will be the selected answer.

Comment: You may suppose that $x_n = a^{q(n)} b^{r(n)}$ and try to find $q(n)$ and $r(n)$. Then limit will be easy-founded

Comment: I'm trying the subsequence $x_1,x_3,x_5,\dots$ which is monotone increasing but I can't see a nice recursion.

Comment: And a few more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545572/recursive-sequence-such-as-x-n2-sqrtx-n1x-n?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429890/find-the-limit-of-the-sequence-a-n-n-ge-0-given-that-a-n12-a-na-n-1?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @rtybase yes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define $y_n = \log(x_n)$. Then we get the linear recurrence

$$y_{n+1} = \frac{y_n + y_{n-1}}{2},$$

which we can immediately solve using [standard methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients): Therefore $$y_n = u \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n + v$$ for some $u$ and $v$. And therefore $\lim x_n = v$. Using the initial conditions we get $v = \frac{1}{3} (\log(a) + 2\log(b))$. Since $\log$ is continuous we therefore get

$$\lim x_n = \exp(\lim y_n) = \exp(v) = (ab^2)^{1/3}$$

as you already claimed.

Comment: Shouldn't be $y_n = u(-1/2)^n\dots$?

Comment: @user2820579 yes indeed, thakns for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

Hint : take the $ln$ (after verifying that $ln(x_n)$ is well-defined !)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it was similar to what flawr suggested (though I cannot tell from the short answer given), but he developed a little bit more the idea.